# Simple flat file CMS (or blog/wiki) engine written in Perl

Tags: cms, wiki, perl

Looking for a CMS (or blog or wiki) engine what has the following attributes:

1. written in Perl (modern style)
2. uses Plack (server Starman or such)
3. **flat file** engine, e.g. requires **no external database engine** (read: allows grepping, and vi-editing on the content)
4. correctly allows/handles UTF-8 content
5. have batteries already included, so uses:

   - most commonly used JavaScript libs (Lightbox and like)
   - any of currently mostly used CSS frameworks, like Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation or like (and/or allows easy template adoption)
6. and **have** its own **plugin API** - so one can easily write plugins into it
7. not abandoned

And would be nice if it has a built-in search engine.

So, simple CMS/blog/wiki what can be used as sort of *publishing platform*.

Is there something in the Perl world what fulfills the above 7 criteria?

#### What I already know

- WebGUI (need a database)
- PearlBee (need a database)
- Bloxsom - could be +- OK, but it is (abandoned?) and CGI based (not PSGI)

Foswiki would be great, because:

- uses flat files
- have built in search engine
- pure Perl
- have macros, plugins and nice community ;)

but:

- it is like a spagethy inside (really old school engine)
- has terrible UTF-8 handling
- extremelly hard to change the site "skin" (templates) and the built-in ones are like from 1994
- not PSGI compliant

Comment: [aneuch](http://www.aneuch.org/), [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/), [kehei](http://kehei-wiki.sourceforge.net/), [podwiki](http://www.daemon.de/PodWiki), [prowiki](http://www.prowiki.org/prowiki/wiki.cgi), [twiki](http://twiki.org/), [walawiki](http://walawiki.org/) might be worth checking out. I don't know about all 7 requirements, so I can't leave an answer.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanx remembering me to re-chech again the http://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php . Maybe something is new. ;)